# Upload Form via iOs

Tags: php, ios, ajax

I have made a ajax upload form. This is working fine on almost all devices. Except for iOs devices (ipad and iphone).

Is it impossible to upload files to a webserver in iOs ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I cite:

"Uploadcare users have noticed that after upgrading to iOS 8.0 they cannot upload files from Safari.

Sad but true. The new iOS version has a bug that renders sending files by browsers impossible. When you choose a file in a form on HTML page and try to submit it, no file is sent in the request. The browser indicates that it’s waiting for a response, but in fact the response never comes."

See here for some details:
http://blog.uploadcare.com/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari/